# Animate google marker along polyline in ios using swift

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, dictionary

I am trying to animate a marker in Google Map along with Polyline. I have a list of lats and longs. I am able to animate marker in my activity but it's only showing the movement of last animation in loop.
I think it's task handling issue but I don't know how to handle task to perform all of animations in loop.

My Code is Below:

```
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        for _ in self.lat{
            self.rotateMarker(coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.lat[count], self.lon[count]), degrees: 0, duration: 3.0 )
            count += 1
        }
    }
```

And My rotateMarker method is

```
    func rotateMarker(coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D, degrees: CLLocationDegrees, duration: Double) {

    // Movement
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(duration)
    rotatingMarker.position = coordinates

    // Center Map View
    let camera = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(coordinates)
    mapView.animate(with: camera)

    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

What I am doing wrong?